# Version mismatch between scipy and poetry

Tags: python, scipy, python-poetry

I'm using the poetry dependency manager for some of my development (RTL-SDR application).  However, when I try to add scipy to the environment (calling `poetry add scipy` inside Windows 11 Powershell), I get the following output:

```
    Using version ^1.10.0 for scipy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

The current project's Python requirement (>=3.11,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - scipy requires Python <3.12,>=3.8, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.12,<4.0

Because no versions of scipy match >1.10.0,<2.0.0
 and scipy (1.10.0) requires Python <3.12,>=3.8, scipy is forbidden.
So, because sdr1 depends on scipy (^1.10.0), version solving failed.

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties

    For scipy, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.11,<3.12"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

However,using `py -V`, I verify that my python version is 3.11.0.  So, everything should work, right?

Suggestions on resolving this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you check what is defined in [tool.poetry.dependencies] in pyproject.toml? Usually this comes from that setting

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#why-is-poetry-telling-me-that-the-current-projects-python-requirement-is-not-compatible-with-one-or-more-packages-python-requirements

Comment: [tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
numpy = "^1.24.1"
matplotlib = "^3.6.3"
pyrtlsdr = "^0.2.93"
pysdr = "^1.2"                                                Nothing pops out that would violate what is called out in my original post.

Comment: The only thing that really strikes me is that the original error message makes what appears to be a nonsensical statement:  "The current project's Python requirement (>=3.11,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:  - scipy requires Python <3.12,>=3.8, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.12,<4.0"  It effectively states that Python 3.11.0 meets the requirements of both the project and scipy.  Where it is getting this "Python >=3.12,<4.0" I don't know.  As I said, I have manually verified that my version of Python is 3.11.0.

Answer (score 4):

> Where it is getting this "Python >=3.12,<4.0" I don't know.

Specifying `python="^3.11.0"` [is equivalent to](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/) `>=3.11,<4.0`.

This indicates that the project is expected to work for *every* version in that range, not just any.

Since Scipy does not support 3.12, the project cannot support 3.12, and therefore cannot meet the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with isn't pretty, and it doesn't answer my questions, but it does work.  As Imre_G suggested, I looked at [tool.poetry.dependencies] in pyproject.toml.  There, I changed the Python requirement from

```
python="^3.11.0"
```

to

```
python="==3.11.0"
```

Apparently, Poetry accepted this as effectively excluding version 3.12 where "^3.11.0" did not.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Apparently, Poetry accepted this as effectively excluding version 3.12 where "^3.11.0" did not." Well, yes; `"^3.11.0"` means `>=3.11.0, <4.0`. Like what the error message says. See the [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/).

Comment: To allow versions 3.11.1, etc., use `python = "~3.11.0"`.